# How to change master web ui port when starting spark in local mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark in local mode (`master = "local[*]"`, see code below). How can I change the master port from `8080` to something else (in this case I need to since `8080` is already occupied). And, since it is occupied, spark master seems just not to start its web ui.

```
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[*]")
                .setAppName("Local RESTWS ML");
        return SparkSession
                .builder()
                .config(conf)
                .getOrCreate();
    }
```

I tried setting the `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT` environment variable without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run spark on local mode, you do not need to start a master node. If u just run the code u posted, without starting a master, u are not going to have a master webui. Instead you will still have the sparkContext web ui at port 4040. If u want to change that port:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setMaster("local[*]")
            .setAppName("Local RESTWS ML")
            .set("spark.ui.port", "4041");
```

or if u want to skip SparkConf:

```
     return SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Local RESTWS ML")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.ui.port", "4041")
            .getOrCreate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The env variable `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT` works only in standalone mode.
Couple of options.

1. Programmatically - like @Panagiotis has suggested.
2. Declaratively - Specify the `spark.ui.port` in spark-defaults.conf or pass as argument to spark-submit invocation like `spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=xxxx`

Note: If the given port is not available, the next ports are tried until a free port is available(controlled by `spark.port.maxRetries` defaulting to 16). For example if `spark.ui.port` is 1000 and if no ports are available till 1016, Spark UI bring up will fail